# Aggregate data to 30 minute intervals

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

A have a table where each row is 300 seconds (or 5 minutes) apart. I need to aggregate the data on every hour and half hour, aggregating everything before and including the hour or half hour.

I've tried this code:

```
SELECT  
to_timestamp(floor(a / 1800 )) * 
1800) 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval_alias, SUM(b) as b_sum
FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY interval_alias
```

...and it aggregates the data on every hour and half hour, but it sum the values post the hour and half hour.

The table looks something like this:

```
a              | b    
-------------------------
1533045600     | 3
1533045900     | 5
1533046200     | 6
1533046500     | 3
1533046800     | 5
1533047100     | 2
1533047400     | 3 
1533047700     | 8
1533048000     | 5
1533048300     | 5
1533048600     | 6
```

The actual result with the above code is:

```
a              | b
-------------------------
1533045600     | 24
1533047400     | 27
```

The desired output is:

```
a              | b
-------------------------
1533045600     | 3
1533047400     | 24
```

Comment: can't reproduce your error. the postet SQL doesn't look correct

Comment: what's the data type of your data column `a`?

Comment: My mistake I've edited the question, both are numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a simpler calculation for the interval_alias and with a GROUP BY you can only select aggregations or the columns that are part of the GROUP BY. (The `SELECT *` you posted in the question didn't look correct...)

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(a/1800)*1800 AS interval_alias,
  SUM(b) AS sum_b
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY interval_alias
```

See example code on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fc91/12/0)

update:
This is close to your desired output but will include a third result as your test data spans over more than a half hour.

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(a/1800)*1800 + SIGN(a%1800)*1800 AS interval_alias,
  SUM(b) AS sum_b
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY interval_alias
ORDER BY interval_alias
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I'm after it gives me the same results not the desired output.